# How to correct macOS Sierra photos people identification

Tags: photos, macos

So, just playing around with photos, and my kids baby pics are crossed over. When they were you they were both bald so it's hard for photos to correctly distinguish them.

How can I correct this in Photos?  In the list, right or option click did nothing. Pic info didn't show much.

Answer (score 1):

Found out maybe 10 minutes after I posted this.

Go to your photos.  Find the one with the bad tagging.  Make sure Face Names are shown (go to View menu), edit as needed